# How do i find repeated characters in a string in C?

Tags: c

So given a string, im trying to find the repeated chars (or letters) and then print them out.  I've tried everything and below is my code:

```
void char_counter(char *str){
    int n = strlen(str);
    int i =0;
    int j;
    char substring[] ={0};

    for(i; i < n; i++){
        j = i + 1;
        if(str[i]== str[j]){
            substring[i] = str[i];
            printf("%c\n", substring[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I know that in python, this would be something as simple as:

```
def char_counter_dup(str):
    char_dict = {}
    list_of_duplicates =[]
    for idx, letter in enumerate(str):
        if letter not in char_dict:
            char_dict[letter] = 1
            list_of_duplicates.append(letter)
        else:
            char_dict[letter] +=1
    return list_of_duplicates, char_dict

my_string = "acabcabcff"
print("List of duplicates is: {}".format(char_counter_dup(my_string)[0]))
```

Since there is not equivalent of `if not in` in C, how do i go about it?

I tried using pointers, while loops, double indexing.

Comment: `char substring[] ={0};` the size of your array is 1, you don't have space to store `n` characters in it.

Comment: `there is not equivalent of if not in in C,` there is `if (!strchr(char_dict, letter))`

Comment: What is a "repeated character"? Take for example the string `"Follow"`... Are both the `o` and `l` characters repeated? Only the `l`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the comparison to Python's `in` suggest that the o's in "follow" would be considered repeated. As does the output from that Python snippet.

Comment: Assuming @Chris is correct, then you can actually use an algorithm very similar to the Python solution, at least if you limit yourself to plain 7-bit ASCII. Then use an array of `128` unsigned integer elements, all initialized to zero. Loop through the string once, using the character as an index into the array, and increase the array element value. Once done, all elements of the array which have a value larger than one are are "repeated".

Comment: There is a lack of clarity here. _"So given a string, im trying to find the repeated chars (or letters) and then print them out."_ What is a "letter" here? Are ASCII characters sufficient, or does the broader class of Unicode letters need to be handled? Does OP desire to only print the duplicate letters, or does OP desire to build a list of duplicates (as in the Python code)? From the Python example it seems that "repeated" means duplicates from the input string, not only letters that are sequentially repeated.

Comment: In Python you have `dict` as part of the standard library. C doesn't provide anything similar, so you will have to build that data structure yourself. If you use C++, you can use a `map` instead.

Comment: Generally, when wanting the frequency of any object within a specified range, you want a **frequency array** to cover the entire range of possible values for that object.  (for ASCII chars, `char arr[128] = {0};` will cover the whole set) For a full explanation of what is frequency array is, and how to use it, a fuller explanation is provided in answer to [How to remove duplicate char in string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63255183/3422102)  An example related to characters is [Find most frequent letter in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65462132/3422102) (*Deep Magic - learn it*`:)`

Comment: Superfluous comment, I know, but  “I've tried everything”?  No, you haven’t.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`memchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memchr) to find if a character occurs in the remainder of the string, replicating the functionality of `in` in Python, but algorithmically, you're better off sorting the string *first* and then looping over it, because then all repeated characters will be contiguous.

*Caveat: I'm not testing to ensure `strdup` succeeded in the following.*

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int compare_chars(const void *a, const void *b) {
    char c = *(char *)a;
    char d = *(char *)b;

    return c == d ?  0 :
           c < d  ? -1 : 1;
}

int main(void) {
    const char *s = "dacabcabcff";
    char *s2 = strdup(s);

    qsort(s2, strlen(s2), 1, compare_chars);

    char last_char = '\0';

    for (size_t i = 0; s2[i]; i++) {
        if (s2[i] == last_char) {
            printf("%c\n", s2[i]);

            // Skip to the next unique character
            // to avoid printing repeated characters 
            // more than once.
            while (s2[i] && s2[i] == last_char) i++;
        }

        last_char = s2[i];
    }  

    free(s2);   
}
```

Of course, the table mentioned by @SomeProgrammerDude in comments scales better as it's an O(n) solution rather than O(n * log n), *but* it does not scale to data sets which involve much larger possible values.

Consider how this would work if we had an array of 32-bit integers. The table to hold them would have to hold *~4 billion* values.

A naive approach would simply iterate over the rest of the string to determine if the same character occurs again.

```
int main(void) {
    const char *s = "dacabcabcff";
    size_t len = strlen(s);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
        int found_again = 0;

        for (size_t j = i + 1; !found_again && j < len; j++) {
            if (s[i] == s[j]) {
                found_again = 1;
            }
        }

        if (found_again) {
            printf("%c\n", s[i]);
        }
    }  
}
```

This poses a problem as it has quadratic or O(n^2) runtime complexity, but also because it may print the same character multiple times.

We *could* write code to remove that character from the remainder of the string, but that adds further work to a solution which is already working too hard.

E.g.

```
int main(void) {
    // Not a string literal so it can be modified.
    char s[] = "dacabcabcff";

    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(s) - 1; i++) {
        int found_again = 0;

        for (size_t j = i + 1; !found_again && j < strlen(s); j++) {
            if (s[i] == s[j]) {
                found_again = 1;
            }
        }

        // Avoiding wrapping everything after this 
        // in a conditional block.
        if (!found_again) continue;

        printf("%c\n", s[i]);

        // Eliminate s[i] from the rest of the string.
        size_t k = i+1;
        for (size_t j = i+1; j < strlen(s); j++) {
            if (s[j] != s[i]) 
                s[k++] = s[j];
        }
        s[k] = '\0';
    }  
}
```

Comment: isn't it an overkill?

Comment: loop executes 45 times. for string length of 11

Comment: The naive version I added, or my original code?

Answer (score -1):

You need the table where you will store the number of occurrences of the char. Then you can print them if that count is larger than `1`

If `o` in `follow` is considered as "repeat" character.

```
void char_counter(const char *str)
{
    size_t chars['~'-' ' + 1] = {0,};  // only from ' ' to `~`

    while(*str)
    {
        if(*str >= ' ' && *str <= '~')
        chars[*str - ' ']++;
        str++;
    }
    for(size_t index = 0; index < sizeof(chars) / sizeof(chars[0]); index++)
    {
        if(chars[index] > 1)
        printf("'%c' - %zu times\n", (char)index + ' ', chars[index]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char_counter("dfslgkdjlfk als sdlk sakl jsdakl jsdlkfasdjkfdlgfjgalk!@#@#%$#%^*&^~~~~dfgdf54fdsdd;lfdf;dsfakl3456459657438553985476");
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/hbcvTsMcb

Comment: Any comment? What is wrong here in your opinion?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but perhaps because you're making an assumption that the character set is ASCII. I have redeeming qualities, but mind-reading isn't one of them.

Comment: One note: `str` _can_ be `const char *`.

Comment: @Chris it is not a real program. only something which demonstrates the **idea**

Comment: @gulpr: Re “it is not a real program. only something which demonstrates the idea”: That is an excuse for claiming the answer is okay. You do not make improvements by excusing things as okay. You look for things that can be improved. If you were criticizing this post, how many issues could you find?

Comment: @EricPostpischil so what is wrong with it? And what is wrong with ASCII