# How to not count the same number twice in a guessing game

Tags: c

I have been stuck on this problem for hours and don't know what to do. The setup I have completes the guessing game and everything works fine except when the user guesses the same guess twice, it is not supposed to use a "try". I don't want to do anything too advanced, I understand that I have to save my last guess in a variable but do not know how to approach that. Thank you for the help.

```
         srand(time(NULL));
         int r = rand() %10 + 1 ;
         int guess;
         int tries = 0;
         int lastguess = 0;


         printf("Welcome user, please guess my number from 1 to 10\n"); ;



         while(1){

         scanf(" %d", &guess);
         tries++;
         if (guess == r) {
         printf("Congratulations, you got it in %d tries\n", tries);

         return 0;
         }

         else if( guess == lastguess) {
         printf("You have already tried this value, try another");
         tries - 1;
         }
         else if( guess < 11 && guess > r) {
         guess = lastguess;
         printf("Guess Lower!\n");

         }
         else if( guess > 0 && guess < r ){
         guess = lastguess;
         printf("Guess Higher!\n ");
         }


         else if( guess > 11) {
         printf("The game will  not continue since you chose\n");
         printf("a number that is not between 1 and 10 :(\n");
         return 0;
         }

         else if( guess < 1){
         printf("The game will not continue since you chose\n");
         printf("a number that is not bewtween 2 and 10 :(\n");
         return 0;
         }
 }
```

Comment: Use a *Frequency Array*, see this answer [How to remove duplicate char in string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63255183/3422102) Let me know if you are still stuck afterwards and I'll help further, if needed. Basically you need `int guessed[10] = {0};` as your frequency array and then increment the index corresponding to the guess. Before you record a guess you check `if (guessed[guess]) { /* already guessed */ }`  If not, it's a valid guess and you just increment `guessed[guess]++;` (you still need your range checks -- this just addresses the duplicate guess issue)

Comment: So Would I set guessed[10] = 0; . I should also place a guessed++; after both of the right guess checks. What should i set before the scan to check the guesses?

Comment: To access it with `guessed[guess]`it should be `int guessed[11] = {0};`, otherwise you'd have to access it with `guessed[guess-1]`. Anyway you should do nothing before the scan

Answer (score 2):

Continuing from my comment, any time you need to keep track of whether (or how many times) a value within a range has been seen, you want a *Frequency Array*. Such as how many times is each letter used in this document, or has the user already guessed `X`?

A frequency array is simply an array with one element for each value in your range. The array is initialized all zero. When you read a value, you increment the index that corresponds to that value, e.g.

```c
array[value]++;
```

So the `array` simply keeps track of how many times a given `value` is seen. In your case to prevent the user from entering the same number more than once and having it count as a valid try -- all you care about is whether `array[value] == 0`. If it does, then `value` has not been entered before.  `if (array[value] != 0)` (or simply `if (array[value])`), you know the user has already provided that value, so it should not count as a valid try.

Think about it for a minute. It takes a bit to wrap your head around what is happening. You start with an array that has an elements that corresponds to each value in your range from `1-10` and each of the elements is initialized `0`. So if the user enters `5`, you will increment (add `+1`) the array index that corresponds to `5`, e.g. `array[5]++;`. So `array[5]` now equals `1`. If you check the index for the value the user enters each time against the value at that index in the array -- if it isn't `0`, you know the user has already entered that value.

Frequency arrays work for *many, many, many* types of **counting** and **uniqueness** problems, so make sure you understand them before moving on. I have another write-up about them at [How to remove duplicate char in string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63255183/3422102) which may help if you are still unclear how they track the guesses entered by your user.

How to implement it in your code? Just add a `int guessed[11] = {0};` array for your frequency array (the `11` instead of `10` just avoids having to map the indexes from a ones-based `1-10` to a zero-based `0-9` since all array indexes are zero-based in C. (plus the cost of 1 extra `int` element in the array to save having to `guess - 1` each time makes sense).

So with an `11` element frequency array to capture your guesses from `1-10` that allows you to track your user's `guess` by incrementing `guessed[guess]++;` with each ***valid*** guess and before considering the guess valid, allows you to check `if (guessed[guess] != 0)` to know that the user has already used that `guess`.

Putting it altogether, (with a short aside first) you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NGUESSES 10     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXC 256        /* max number of characters for each entry */
```

(**note:** don't use *Magic-Numbers* in your code, if you need a constant... You now have a single convenient location at the top of your code where you can change the game to use `15`, `20`, ... whatever number of guesses, without having to pick through all array declarations, `if(...)` statements, loop limits, etc... to make the change)

**Declare Your Frequency Array**

```
int main (void) {

    srand(time(NULL));
    
    char buf[MAXC];                             /* buffer (array) for all user-input */
    int r = rand() % NGUESSES + 1,
        guess,
        guessed[NGUESSES + 1] = {0},            /* frequency array + 1 for range 1 - 10 */
        tries = 0;
```

Your `lastguess` is no longer needed. The hours of trying to make that work for check if the user had already entered a guess has been replaced by your frequency array `guessed[]`.

**Read All User Input With a Line-Oriented Input Function**

```
    /* don't use Magic-Numbers in your code, use a constant */
    printf ("\nWelcome user, please guess my number from 1 to %d\n", NGUESSES);

    while (1) {
        printf ("\nguess[%2d] : ", tries + 1);  /* prompt for entry each time */
        
        if (fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin) == NULL) { /* read every input into buffer/validate */
            puts ("(user canceled input)");     /* ctrl+d, manual EOF is valid input */
            return 0;                           /* allow user to cancel */
        }
        
        /* use sscanf to parse guess from buf - validate EVERY conversion */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &guess) != 1) {  /* " " not needed, %d ignores whitespace */
            fputs ("  error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
            continue;
        }
```

Always take user-input with a *line-oriented* input function so what remains in your input buffer `stdin` does NOT depend on the `scanf()` *conversion specifier* used or whether a *matching* failure occurs. Try entering `"bananas"` as your input -- and you will quickly see why. Instead read with `fgets()` into an array and then use `sscanf()` to parse the values you need from the array (works just like `scanf()` but reads from your array instead of `stdin`). Why?

That way no matter what the user inputs, your `while()` loop doesn't spin off into an infinite loop if the user enters a non-integer value because --- you have read the entire line with `fgets()` so nothing will remain unread in `stdin` and regardless of whether the *conversion* succeeds or fails, `stdin` is ready for the next input attempt and not full of characters that `scanf()` left behind.

(with `scanf()` when a *matching-failure* occurs, character extraction from `stdin` ceases at that point so the bad input is left ***unread*** in `stdin`)

That's why you use `fgets()` (or POSIX `getline()`) to read every user-input.

**Validate The Input Is In Range**

```
        if (guess < 1 || NGUESSES < guess) {    /* validate guess in range */
            fprintf (stderr, "  error: %d not between 1 and %d\n", guess, NGUESSES);
            continue;
        }
```

**Check Your Frequency Array To See If `guess` Already Entered**

```
        if (guessed[guess]) {   /* check if freq array non-zero at guess index */
            fprintf (stderr, "  error: %d was a previous guess.\n", guess);
            continue;
        }
        guessed[guess]++;       /* increment index for guess indicating guess used */
        tries++;
```

Only now do you know you have a valid input that will constitute a try.

**Check Victory or Prompt "Higher!" or "Lower!"**

```
        if (guess == r) {       /* check victory */
            printf ("Congratulations, you got it in %d tries\n", tries);
            return 0;
        }
        else if (r < guess)     /* prompt for high guess */
            puts ("  Guess Lower!");
        else                    /* prompt for low guess */
            puts ("  Guess Higher!");
    }
}
```

That's it -- done. If you will notice the indentation - that is the complete program.

**Example Use/Output**

With intentional bad non-integer input and duplicate guesses and guesses out-of-range, you can exercise the program with:

```
$ ./bin/guess_1-10

Welcome user, please guess my number from 1 to 10

guess[ 1] :  My dog has fleas and my cat has none :)
  error: invalid integer input.

guess[ 1] : 6
  Guess Higher!

guess[ 2] : 0
  error: 0 not between 1 and 10

guess[ 2] : 11
  error: 11 not between 1 and 10

guess[ 2] : 6
  error: 6 was a previous guess.

guess[ 2] : 1
  Guess Higher!

guess[ 3] : 3
  Guess Higher!

guess[ 4] : 5
  Guess Higher!

guess[ 5] : 7
  Guess Higher!

guess[ 6] : 10
  Guess Lower!

guess[ 7] : 8
  Guess Higher!

guess[ 8] : 9 ... drum roll ... and
Congratulations, you got it in 8 tries
```

What if the user cancels input by generating a manual `EOF` with <kbd>Ctrl + d</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl + z</kbd> on windows)? A manual `EOF` is valid input for your program, so you should always respect a user's wish to cancel input by using it, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/guess_1-10

Welcome user, please guess my number from 1 to 10

guess[ 1] : 3
  Guess Lower!

guess[ 2] : (user canceled input)
```

By using `fgets()`, you simply ***check the return***, as you do with EVERY input function you use, and if it is `NULL`, you know the user generated a manual `EOF`, so simply exit at that point.

**Full Code**

The full code to make it easy to copy/paste/compile/test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NGUESSES 10     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXC 256        /* max number of characters for each entry */

int main (void) {

    srand(time(NULL));
    
    char buf[MAXC];                             /* buffer (array) for all user-input */
    int r = rand() % NGUESSES + 1,
        guess,
        guessed[NGUESSES + 1] = {0},            /* frequency array + 1 for range 1 - 10 */
        tries = 0;
    
    /* don't use Magic-Numbers in your code, use a constant */
    printf ("\nWelcome user, please guess my number from 1 to %d\n", NGUESSES);

    while (1) {
        printf ("\nguess[%2d] : ", tries + 1);  /* prompt for entry each time */
        
        if (fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin) == NULL) { /* read every input into buffer/validate */
            puts ("(user canceled input)");     /* ctrl+d, manual EOF is valid input */
            return 0;                           /* allow user to cancel */
        }
        
        /* use sscanf to parse guess from buf - validate EVERY conversion */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &guess) != 1) {  /* " " not needed, %d ignores whitespace */
            fputs ("  error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
            continue;
        }
        
        if (guess < 1 || NGUESSES < guess) {    /* validate guess in range */
            fprintf (stderr, "  error: %d not between 1 and %d\n", guess, NGUESSES);
            continue;
        }
        
        if (guessed[guess]) {   /* check if freq array non-zero at guess index */
            fprintf (stderr, "  error: %d was a previous guess.\n", guess);
            continue;
        }
        guessed[guess]++;       /* increment index for guess indicating guess used */
        tries++;
        
        if (guess == r) {       /* check victory */
            printf ("Congratulations, you got it in %d tries\n", tries);
            return 0;
        }
        else if (r < guess)     /* prompt for high guess */
            puts ("  Guess Lower!");
        else                    /* prompt for low guess */
            puts ("  Guess Higher!");
    }
}
```

Give it a go, let me know if it does what you need, and let me know if you have further questions. Make sure you understand theses concepts before moving on -- and I'm here to help if you are still stuck.